# No overload for method 'addItem' takes 3 arguments (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, wcf

I'm trying to call a function from a WCF service I've made, it's supposed to add a new row to the database. Now that I wrote the function in the Controller it keeps giving me the error "No overload for method 'addItem' takes 3 arguments".

ItemController (in Create function):

```
srvc.addItem(newItm.Namn, newItm.Pris, newItm.CategoryID);
```

Service2.svc:

```
public void addItem(string name, int price, int ctgID)
{
      Database1Entities1 tbl = new Database1Entities1();
      Vara newItm = new Vara() {
            Namn=name,
            Pris=price,
            CategoryID=ctgID,
        };
      tbl.Vara.Add(newItm);
      try
      {
      tbl.SaveChanges();
      }
```

Service2.cs:

```
[OperationContract]
    void addItem(string name, int price, int ctgID);
```

This is all the relevant information, I believe, tell me if there is something I have missed. What could cause this problem?

Comment: make sure that these are right variables `newItm.Namn, newItm.Pris, newItm.CategoryID` meaning string, and two integers

Comment: If you have changed method signature in your WCF service and did not update your service reference in your consuming application that could be one cause.

Comment: Make sure that you update your service reference in your client app in this case your MVC app. So that the correct wsdl will be reference with the updated addItem method signature.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help when I update the service reference. Just tells me "invalid arguments" rather then "3 arguments" now.